# SceneBuilder - Sense of on action

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I started working with JavaFx and the SceneBuilder 5 days ago. I have one question. Under the label "code" I have the fx:id (Am I right, that this is the method-name) and the field on-Action. What's the sense of the on-Action-field?

Thanks for your help :-)

Best regards,

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **On Action** field is the name of the event listener method for actionable components. For example, add a button and add the name *buttonOnAction* to the field **On Action**. Now go to the menu *View -> Show Sample Controller Skeleton*. You should see this snippet:

```
@FXML
void buttonOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
}
```

This method must also be the mentioned by name in the fxml file of course, which should have an entry like this:

```
<Button onAction="#buttonOnAction" text="Button" />
```

Therefore, clicking that button fires the method *buttonOnAction*.